# how to protect routes in next js 13.4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js13

I created an e-commerce website using Node.js, MongoDB, and Next.js. When a user logs in, I store their token using Redux Toolkit. Now, I want to protect my routes using this token. I have attempted to use middleware.js to access Redux data, but it is not working. How can I protect my routes in Next.js 13.4?

I tried to retrieve Redux data in the middleware.js file, but it isn't functioning as expected

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you find the solution?. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @AliHassan Yes, I will create a component to wrap all children with this component and write conditions to protect all routes